# How to split page after adding the image using HTML2Canvas and jspdf

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf, html2canvas

Using html2canvas and JsPDF for converting HTML to pdf and using the below code for generating the code
this code will give convert the complete HTML of the div to a single image and will show in the pdf as a single page.

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

    htmltoPDF()
    {
        // parentdiv is the html element which has to be converted to PDF
        html2canvas(document.querySelector("#parentdiv")).then(canvas => {
    
          var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [canvas.width, canvas.height]);
    
          var imgData  = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
          pdf.addImage(imgData,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
          pdf.save('converteddoc.pdf');
    
      });

}
```

For split the code i used below code which split the pages into the multiple pages but not spliting the space correctly because my pdf has small images attached pdf.

```
var imgWidth = 210;
var pageHeight = 295;
var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
var heightLeft = imgHeight;

enter code here

var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
var position = 0;

doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
heightLeft -= pageHeight;

while (heightLeft >= 0) {
position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
doc.addPage();
doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
heightLeft -= pageHeight;
}
doc.save( 'file.pdf');
```

Is there any approach to split the page according to the static height which split the image from a particular position?

Answer (score 5):

1. First we have to restrict canvas image height and width

```
html2canvas(divToPrint, {
        width: 2480,
        height: 3508
      }).then((canvas) => {

})
```

2. Then we can split this canvas image easily.

```
html2canvas(divToPrint, {
        width: 2480,
        height: 3508
      }).then((canvas) => {
        let imgWidth = 400;
        let pageHeight = 480;
        let imgHeight =
          ((canvas.height * imgWidth) / 2454)*1.24;
        var heightLeft = imgHeight;

        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        const pdf = new jsPDF({
          orientation: "p",
          unit: "mm",
          format: [400, 480],
        });

        let position = 0;
        pdf.setFillColor(248);
        pdf.rect(0, 0, 400, 480, "F");
        pdf.addImage(Header, "JPEG", 0, 0, 400, 400);
        pdf.setFontSize(35);
        pdf.text('SMRF 360', 10, 420);
        pdf.setFontSize(15);
        pdf.text(`Feedback report`, 10, 433)
        pdf.text('March 2021', 10, 440)
        pdf.addPage();
        pdf.addImage(imgData, "PNG", 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;

        while (heightLeft >= 0) {
          position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
          pdf.addPage();
          pdf.addImage(imgData, "PNG", 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
          heightLeft -= pageHeight;
        }
        pdf.save("Result.pdf");
      });
```

Comment: In your first step, you repeated the height twice.

Comment: @N.Dias fixed with thanks

Comment: what is header in pdf.addImage(Header, "JPEG", 0, 0, 400, 400); @N.Dias

Comment: It works for me!! great job!

Comment: @AjithKumar bro Comment or ignore that line with Header like below                     
     // pdf.addImage(Header, "JPEG", 0, 0, 400, 400);

Answer (score 0):

First set doc instance to accept unit as 'pt'. Post this the next step would be to check if image is greater than page size, if so, image will span over multiple pages, as we have docHeight with us, we would be able to get part of the image that would be contained in current page. Now, repeat this for next page (remaining image is say larger again for next page). Code would like below (Here, I wanted image to only occupy 0.8 of page width, height is adjusted accordingly):

```
  //Read Canvas to be exported
  const appRolesElement = document.getElementById('app-roles-element');
  const appRolesCanvas = await html2canvas(appRolesElement, { onclone: function (document) {
      //Different style requirement for export
      document.querySelectorAll('.right-wrapper').forEach(el => {
        el.style.marginLeft = '0px';
      })
  }});

  const doc = new jsPDF({
    compress: true,
    orientation: 'p',
    unit: 'pt',
    format: 'a4'
  });
  var docWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
  var docHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
  let heightInPlace = 0;
  let appRolesImageDisplayHeight = getDisplayHeight(appRolesCanvas.height, appRolesCanvas.width, docWidth*0.8);
  let appRolesIterationCounter = 0;
  let appRolesSourceClipStartY = 0;

  //Keep checking if a new page is required
  while(appRolesImageDisplayHeight > 0) {
    if(appRolesIterationCounter > 0) {
      doc.addPage();
      heightInPlace = 10;
    }
    ++appRolesIterationCounter;
    const remainingHeightInPage = docHeight - heightInPlace;
    const sourceHeightToBeDisplayed = getSourceHeight(remainingHeightInPage, appRolesCanvas.width, docWidth);
    const clippedImage = await convertURIToImageData(appRolesImage, appRolesCanvas.width, sourceHeightToBeDisplayed, appRolesSourceClipStartY);
    doc.addImage(clippedImage, 'JPEG', 10, heightInPlace, docWidth * 0.8, remainingHeightInPage * 0.8);
    heightInPlace += (remainingHeightInPage * 0.8) + 5;
    appRolesImageDisplayHeight = appRolesImageDisplayHeight - remainingHeightInPage;
    appRolesSourceClipStartY += sourceHeightToBeDisplayed;
  }
  doc.save("export.pdf");


  const getDisplayHeight = (sourceHeight, sourceWidth, displayWidth) => {
    return (displayWidth/sourceWidth)*sourceHeight;
  };

  const getSourceHeight = (displayHeight, sourceWidth, displayWidth) => {
    return displayHeight*(sourceWidth/displayWidth);
  }
```

Additionally, please use attribute data-html2canvas-ignore for ignoring contents from exports.